# Swift SpriteKit: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT. Cannot cast value of type SKLabelNode?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sigabrt

So I was finishing up a project, and when I ran it and it crashed and I got the Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error and i looked at the description and it gave me this:

Could not cast value of type 'SKLabelNode' (0x108ed0b78) to 'Koala_Hop.MCTPointLabel' (0x108091da0).
(lldb)

for this line of code:

```
func loadHighscore() {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let highscoreLabel = childNodeWithName("highscoreLabel") as! MCTPointLabel //line with error
    highscoreLabel.setTo(defaults.integerForKey("highscore"))
```

Really confused, need help figuring this out! Thanks in advance!

```
    **EDIT**: The declaration of highscoreLabel:
      func addPoints() {
    let pointsLabel = MCTPointLabel(num: 0)
    pointsLabel.fontColor = UIColor.brownColor()
    pointsLabel.position = CGPointMake(30.0, view!.frame.size.height - 40)
    pointsLabel.name = "pointsLabel"
    addChild(pointsLabel)


    let highScoreLabels = MCTPointLabel(num: 0)
    highScoreLabels.position = CGPointMake(view!.frame.size.width - 40, view!.frame.size.height - 40)
    addChild(highScoreLabels)

    let highscoreLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "High Score")
    highscoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor.brownColor()
    highscoreLabel.fontSize = 16.0
    highscoreLabel.fontName = "Chalkduster"
    highscoreLabel.name = "highscoreLabel"
    highscoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(620, 310)
    addChild(highscoreLabel)

   }
```

Comment: is your label with the name "highscoreLabel" of type MCTPointLabel?

Comment: is the node `highscoreLabel` of the type MCTPointLabel? the compiler think its an `SKLabelNode`

Comment: No, I don't think so. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: well, where do you declare the node `highscoreLabel`?

Comment: In a function in GameScene.

Comment: Could you edit the post with that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change inside of your GameScene the declaration for the High score label:

```
let highscoreLabel = MCTPointsLabel(text: "High Score")
```

Assuming that the MCTPointsLabel inherits from `SKLabelNode` everything will work fine. You have to make sure that if you force typecast a class that you really do in fact have an object of that class. When you said this:

```
let highscoreLabel = childNodeWithName("highscoreLabel") as! MCTPointLabel
```

You typecast the label as a `MCTPointLabel`, but because your highscoreLabel before was actually declared as an `SKLabelNode`, you weren't able to typecast and received the error.

Hope this helps, let me know if you need clarification.

**Edit**: Try this instead:

```
var highscoreLabel = MCTPointsLabel(num: 0)
highscoreLabel.text = "High Score"
```

Comment: I added that, but it's saying "Cannot find initializer for type MCTPointLabel that accepts..."

Comment: oh did you not implement that initializer? Ok which initializer did you implement?

Comment: Im kinda confused. I don't think i have an initializer.

Comment: How do you normally make MCTPointLabels?

Comment: In the MCTPointLabel.swift file and then adding them as needed in GameScene

Comment: yeah but how do you initialize them? I noticed you have the method `num` for it, so thats one way. do you have inside of MCTPointLabel.swift a regular `init` method?

Comment: I believe so. Its the init(num: Int) super.init() jazz.

Comment: Ok so does it just change the label's text property with the Integer you pass and thats it?

Comment: Yes. Is there more to be added?

Comment: Nope, check my edit above. that should get rid of your error :)

Answer (score 0):

Clearly `childNodeWithName("highscoreLabel")` is not an MCTPointLable.

Force casts (with `!`) are generally avoidable and are likely to lead to runtime issues. You need to work out what the possible results of `childNodeWithName("highscoreLabel")` are and make sure that you handle all possibilities or find the information that you need another way.

Comment: It won't let me even run it without the !

Comment: The node with the label is an SKLabelNode not the MCTPointLabel (visible in your updated question). That is why the cast is failing (not being allowed when you don't force it).